# Memory difference iterating over frozen set vs set

Tags: python

When using `for x in obj` notation, does iterating over a frozenset use less memory than a set? Or when is there a memory advantage to using a frozen set opposed to a set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [python2.7 source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5ef28c22dc24/Objects/setobject.c#l1044),  the empty frozen set is a singleton and making a frozenset from an existing frozenset simply returns the old reference.  Otherwise, there doesn't seem to be any significant *memory* advantage as both `frozenset_new` and `set_new` typically end up calling `make_new_set` with the same arguments.

The *reason* to use a frozenset rather than a regular set is to reap the benefits of immutability -- e.g. to use an instance because it is hashible or because it is meant to be a constant.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt there is going to be a significant (if any) memory savings from using `frozenset` over `set`.  The reason to use a `frozenset` is that it is hashable, so you can use it as a dictionary key (or as an element of another set).